# Master-Detail Collectionview in .Net Maui

Tags: .net, xaml, collectionview, maui

In my collectionview on .Net Maui Im trying to have Categories, then items per category. This is trivial with viewmodel and Linq, List, or even array indexes. such as in Blazor

```
foreach(var cat in viewModel.Categories)
{
   <select id="@cat" binding=@viewModel.Categories.Where(z=> z.Category == cat)>
   </select>  
}
```

But im having trouble doing this with CollectionView

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionViewMenuPerCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" ItemsLayout="VerticalList" Margin="10" >
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label text="{Binding CategoryName}" FontSize="34">
                <CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewPerCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MenuViewModel}}, Path=Menu.Items.Where(z=> z.Category == @CategoryName?}" ItemsLayout="VerticalList">
                   <!-- Each Item in sub collectionview for each category --> 
                </CollectionView>
      </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I have see ICollectionView filtering for WPF but dont see for Maui

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping

Comment: after searching 3 days.. answered in 7 seconds.. this is helpful. thanks

Comment: As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `CollectionView` supports displaying grouped data, and defines the following properties that control how it will be presented:

- **IsGrouped**, of type `bool`, indicates whether the underlying data should be displayed in groups. The default value of this property is
  false.
- **GroupHeaderTemplate**, of type `DataTemplate`, the template to use for the header of each group.
- **GroupFooterTemplate**, of type `DataTemplate`, the template to use for the footer of each group.

These properties are backed by `BindableProperty` objects, which means that the properties can be targets of data bindings.

The process for grouping data, therefore, is to:

- Create a type that models a single item.
- Create a type that models a single group of items.
- Create an IEnumerable collection, where T is the type that models
  a single group of items. This collection is a collection of groups,
  which stores the grouped data. Add data to the IEnumerable
  collection.

For more information, you can check document: [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping).